# Having trouble including JavaScript Variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a file with this code:

```
var famname = guterriez;
```

And another HTML file family.html where I have included the location of the file in the head. I need to display the variable in a `p` element, and possibly in other locations on my site.

I would appreciate some help / tips on how to do this as I've done some research and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Please show your actual code and desired HTML and what you have tried.  `document.createElement()` creates DOM nodes and `parent.appendChild(node)` inserts them into the page.

Comment: guterriez need to be quoted. var famname = "guterriez";

Comment: @jfriend00 I was now able to achieve it by using .innerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If guterriez is not another variable but a string, then you have to put it into quotation marks. Like mentioned above.
Something like this might work for you, if you want to display the code in various locations on your page:

I.e. if you have a `<div>` or a `<table>` where you want to dispaly it:

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
<table id="MyTable"><tr><td id="MyCell"></td></tr>
```

The following JS Code will display the code in the mentioned above elements by calling them with their ID:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML =  famname;
    document.getElementById("MyCell").innerHTML =  famname;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to integrate your JS file into your HTML, and reference variables defined there:

### config.js

```
var txtVar = "This is some text";
```

### page.html

```
<script src="config.js" />
<p id="textBlock"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("textBlock").innerText = txtVar;
</script>
```

See code snippet below for a runnable example.

```js
var txtVar = "This is some text";

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("textBlock").innerText = txtVar;
};
```

```html
<p id="textBlock"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `guterriez` is a string that you would like to assign to the variable `famname`. In that case, it needs to be enclosed in quotation marks to denote the fact that it is a string rather than a variable named `guterriez` (which presumably doesn't exist).

Try this:

```
var famname = "guterriez";
```

Then, you want to use `innerText` to assign this value to the `p` element in your HTML file. Try using [`document.getElementsByTagName("p")[index]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) to access the node and then assign `innerText`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText = famname;
```

```js
var famname = "guterriez";
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText = famname;
```

```html
<p></p>
```